# Is it possible to match table data with an array and turn it into a html link in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, filter

I currently have a jQuery script that matches the values from my table to an array to find a corresponding url and output it as html. It works fine however I would like to keep my array private (so that all of the data cannot be viewed in the inspector if a match isn't found) and from my understanding that cannot be done with javascript. I am already using PHP to dynamically create the table so I was wondering whether this would be possible.

```js
var profiles = [{
    "name": "Susie",
    "link": "www.google.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "link": "www.yahoo.com"
  }
];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').each(function(index, item) {
    var value = $(item).find('td').eq(1).text();
    var exist = profiles.filter(c => c.name == value);
    if (exist.length > 0) {

      var link = exist[0].link;

      $(item).find('td').eq(1).html("<a href='" + link + "'>" + value + "</a>");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1
        <td>Susie</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I was thinking of using a JSON file to store the data but I am not sure where to go from there.

```
$data = '{"Susie": "www.google.com","John": "www.yahoo.com"}';
$array = json_decode($somedata, TRUE);
```

Comment: After making $data, you can do assign $data to javascript variable in a script tag.
`var profiles = <?php echo $data ?>`

Comment: @DanishHakimKhan wouldn't that make all of the $data visible to the user regardless of having a match? as that's what I would like to avoid

Comment: To hide the URLs, you'd need to build some Ajax that sends the selection to your server and gets back the URL. But what's then stopping someone from just selecting each option in sequence and seeing all the URLs that way? Seems like you'd spend a lot of effort implementing this, for very minimal gain.

Comment: @GregSchmidt there is no way for someone to select any options. The table displays specific names at a given time which can change periodically and I want to limit the user's access to only the links associated with the names that are displayed at the time.

Comment: By "select option", I meant "click the names that you have presented to them". Are you okay with people seeing all the links associated with the selected names that are shown? If so, then only include those particular links in the JavaScript when you generate the page. If not, then the detail that you're only allowing some at a given time is irrelevant to the problem.